# Executing code when the scrollview swipes

Tags: iphone

How can code be linked to the swipes of a UIScrollView?

If the user swipes left I would like to decrement a counter and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your counter value is tied to contents offset then you can set `UIScrollView`'s delegate and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` method in it. There you can check `contentOffset` value and change your counter accordingly.

Comment: actually if your scrollview contains UIImageView's only then if you add them as subviews in right order and remove them using -removeFromSuperView, then I'm almost sure that their index in subviews array will be the same as index you calculate form offset... so you can retag your imageviews using array indexes or even don't use tags at all, but use image's index in subviews array instead

Comment: Although I admit that that may look unreliable. Probably you can also use some kind of extra container view for images - just to make sure that they're the only subviews you handle...

Comment: I know. it makes sense now. I was a little retarded. better to get some sleep once in a while. ;)